# Having difficulty using a method on useEffect, missing dependency and useCallback error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

This is my code:

```
  const dfEventQuery = async (event: string) => {
    const {
      data: { result }
    } = await axios.post("/api/df_event_query", { event, userId });
    for (let msg of result.fulfillmentMessages) {
      const botSay: MessageDataType = { speaks: "bot", msg };
      setMessages(oldMessages => [...oldMessages, botSay]);
    }
  };
  const resolveInXSeconds = (x: number) =>
  new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(x);
    }, x * 1000);
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    dfEventQuery("Welcome");
    if (inputRef.current) inputRef.current.focus();
    const sendShopWelcome = async () => {
      await resolveInXSeconds(1);
      dfEventQuery("WELCOME_SHOP");
      setShopWelcomeSent(true);
      setShowChatbot(true);
    };
    if (window.location.pathname === "/shop" && !shopWelcomeSent) {
      sendShopWelcome();
    }
    history.listen(() => {
      if (history.location.pathname === "/shop" && !shopWelcomeSent) {
        sendShopWelcome();
      }
    });
  }, [shopWelcomeSent, history]);
```

I have this error:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dfEventQuery'. Either
>   include it or remove the dependency array

but when i add it on the array: [shopWelcomeSent, history, dfEventQuery] I get this error:

> The 'dfEventQuery' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook
>   (at line 201) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the
>   'dfEventQuery' definition into its own useCallback() Hook

I've been stuck with it for hours and just can't wrap my head why this don't work?

Comment: where is this `dfEventQuery` coming from?

Comment: @skyboyer i'm editing, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so in this case it's easier just to wrap function into `useCallback` listing all its dependencies there:

```
const dfEventQuery = useCallback(async (event: string) => {
  const {
    data: { result }
  } = await axios.post("/api/df_event_query", { event, userId });
  for (let msg of result.fulfillmentMessages) {
    const botSay: MessageDataType = { speaks: "bot", msg };
    setMessages(oldMessages => [...oldMessages, botSay]);
  }
}, [userId]);
```

and listing it into `useEffect`'s dependencies.

But honestly, I'd expect Eslint not complaining on missing dependency since in your code it will be recreated in relevant render cycle and no "stale closure" issue will happen anyway.

[UPD] find similar case in thread https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920#issuecomment-467212561 but don't see any comment either if that's expected(and why) or if it's legit to have such a function out of useEffect's deps.

Comment: Thank you for saving my day, I'm new in hooks, saved lot of time